# Tax Inclusive Products and tax rules

Tags: magento-2.1, catalog, tax

I have **6% and 0% tax zones**.

And I have the following settings:

> Stores > settings > configuration > Sales > Tax
>
> Calculation Settings > Tax Calculation Method Based On > Total
>
> Calculation Settings > Tax Calculation Based On > Shipping Address
>
> Calculation Settings > Catalog Prices > Including Tax
>
> Calculation Settings > Apply Tax On > Original Price Only

Now, I have a perfume product with an original price of 17. Whenever I set my shipping address to trigger 6% tax, it calculates fine:

**Original Price: 17

Price: 16.04

Tax Percent: 6%

Tax Amount: 0.96

Total: 17**

But whenever I set my **shipping address** to trigger 0% tax, calculation is not I expected it to be:

**Original Price: 17

Price 16.04

Tax Amount 0

Tax Percent 0%

Total 16.04**

Here's what I want whenever I trigger 0% tax:

**Original Price: 17

Price 17

Tax Amount 0

Tax Percent 0%

Total 17**

Is there a way I can do this setting on Magento v2.1.2?